# Optimizing the non-differentiable minimum in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, loss-function, optimization

I have the following loss function

[image]

and I optimize it using SGD in tensorflow. The $\phi$ is a soft approximation of the minimum since the minimum is not differentiable, I used the following approximations:

[image]

where k is a negative integer I also tried the formulas [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35191/a-differentiable-approximation-to-the-minimum-function),
yet the model converges very quickly to a local minimum.

Is there any other way to calculate the minimum?

Comment: If I understand correctly, couldn't you use the negative softmax?

Comment: can you explain more, I didn't understand

Comment: Are you trying to find the minimum $a_j$? If so, use softmax with negative arguments.